# how to expand a huffman node after compression

Tags: java, algorithm, compression, nodes, huffman-code

I collapsed all of huffman nodes into one node and trying to build a tree by that node and make a code for each character(huffman leaf) but I can't manage it

I have already tried to write a method but it didn't work because it stops when the first code is created for the first character

this is my method:

```java
    public String createKey(Node node,String s){
        if(node.right==null&&node.left==null) {
            hashMap.put(node, s);
            s="";
        }
        if (node.left!=null)
            return createKey(node.left,s+"0");
        if(node.right!=null)
            return createKey(node.right,s+"1");
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: Please post how you are creating your tree, sample input, and expected output.

Comment: @BakonJarser it was too long I wrote it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

It's usually best to have a single return statement than to have multiple return statements.  Your code doesn't visit right nodes because you are returning before that code is ever reached.  Something like this will visit every node.  You might have to play with the formatting of the results a bit.

```
public String createKey(Node node,String s){
    if(node.right == null && node.left == null) {
        hashMap.put(node, s);
        s="";
    }
    if (node.left != null)
        s += createKey(node.left, s + "0");
    if(node.right != null)
        s += createKey(node.right, s + "1");
    return s;
}
```

Something like this would also work and maybe be easier to format results:

```
public String createKey(Node node,String s){
    if(node.right == null && node.left == null) {
        hashMap.put(node, s);
        s="";
    }
    else if (node.left != null && node.right != null)
       s = createKey(node.left, s + "0") + " " + createKey(node.right, s + "1");
    else if (node.left != null)
        s = createKey(node.left, s + "0");
    else if(node.right != null)
        s = createKey(node.right, s + "1");
    return s;
}
```